# How to extract only the weight from the title using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I need to get the weight for below titles? Since they aren't follow the same way I couldn't get the desired results.

- Pommes d'Aquitaine et mangue (dès 4 mois) - 2 x 130 g (Babybio)
- Céréales vanille avec quinoa - à partir de 6 mois - 220 g (Babybio)
- Ratatouille riz (dès 12 mois) 2 x 200 g (Babybio)
- Pomme de terre, petits pois et jambon (dès 8 mois) 2 x 200 g
- Fondue de carotte et maïs doux au quinoa (dès 12 mois) 230 g (Babybio)
- Gourdes de fruits: pomme d'Aquitaine, poire et pêche - dès 6 mois - 4 x 90 g (Babybio)
- Douceur de panais du Val de Loire, carotte et riz (dès 12 mois) 230 g (Babybio)

Expecting results:

```
2 x 130 g
220 g
2 x 200 g
230 g
4 x 90 g 
230 g
```

I tried this pattern:

```
[0-9]+ x \d+ g
```

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: @Lucas Wieloch, I tried regex101.com , but my syntax isn't correct, that's why I post this question

Comment: provide whatever you tried

Comment: My syntax is in my question   , [0-9]+ x \d+ g

Comment: Yes indeed, my bad sorry

Comment: It's fine, with that I'm getting only 1, 3, 4, 6 weights only. I need rest too

Comment: What is the regex flavor/programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\d+( ?x ?\d+)? g
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PnBZqd/1)

This allow:

- 220 g
- 220x10 g
- 10 x23 g
- 45x 78 g
- ...

Comment: Thanks, your and Lucas Wieloch's answers are corrects!!

Comment: Hello, I was bit hurry to say this was correct. I have little issue with your answer. I'm getting " x 130" instead of  "2 x 130 g" ( my first example), for the second example its fine. Please can you see this? Thanks

Comment: That strange. please look again in the demo example: https://regex101.com/r/gkp5G6/1

Comment: I just changed as ([0-9 x]+?\d+ g) according to my purpose. Anyways thanks for the support!!!

Comment: My pleasuer ( ;

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Your regex was missing only the cases that there was not `x`

```
 [0-9]+( x )?\d+ g
```

The `(...)` captures everything enclosed in it, and the `?` captures one occurrence or none.

Comment: I did not try to change or improve your regex, I just added a statement that was missing. @SeaSharp improved it quite a lot you should check it out on regex101

Comment: Thanks Lucas Wieloch,I have only one chance to accept the answer, sorry about that.